How to autoselect user at login screen without pressing enter
I use exactly one user to login at the login screen.
I don't want to press enter before I can enter the password.
How can I edit this behavior?
Enabling org.gnome.login-screen via dconf-Editor didn't have any effect.
Thanks in advance.
E: Tested autologin + '/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command -l' as startcommand -> screen black when not moving mouse
After this I tested 'loginctl lock-session' -> same: screen black when not moving mouse

Install lightdm by running sudo apt-get install lightdm and sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm. This will autoselect the user and require the password.

Fractional Scaling was disabled after the lightdm login screen. After setting fractional scaling to 125% the mousepointer was tiny as long its on the background image. At windows it got back it's normal size. Thanks for your idea but it didn't work for me.

Ubuntu GNOME 24.04 uses GDM by default, not LightDM; which DM are you using?

as far as I know gdm3 by default.
The command from the first comment will install lightdm and change from gdm3 to lightdm as far as I know.

IIRC you used to be able to just type the password if there's only a single user (or that user was selected)? Meaning, at the GDM screen, just don't hit Enter and just start typing the password
